# How to create form field highlight similar to Groupon login

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Is there a way to use css or jquery to create a simple border around focused form field.  I would like something similar to [Groupon's login page](https://www.groupon.com/login).

Comment: Whatever they use, it's not working with FF10 ... A simple onFocus/focus lost event listener should be enough no ? Edit: neither in IE7, chrome only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the console in Chrome and they aren't doing anything special to the input on `focus`. They aren't changing the class or the inline style. Here's the user agent style for input for webkit-based browsers:

```
input, input[type="password"], input[type="search"], isindex {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px inset;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  cursor: auto;
}

input, textarea, keygen, select, button, isindex, datagrid {
  margin: 0em;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: -webkit-auto;
}
```

I hope this gives you an idea of how it works, but I think it's just general behavior of the browser.